# How to setup Full Node with IXI MAM?

Tags: iri-node, masked-authenticated-messaging, ixi

I have mounted some Full Nodes and wrote a [post in Hello IOTA Forum](https://forum.helloiota.com/2424/Setting-up-a-VPS-IOTA-Full-Node-from-scratch) with a tutorial to do this from scratch. Now I am looking for info to setup a **Full Node with MAM support**. I have been searching and asking but there is not much info out there. Does anybody knows which extra steps would require to mount a Full Node like this? We are basically trying to relay some sensors (XDK, Arduino) over the Tangle by using MAM. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** after some research I found out that using MAM built in on the Full Node might not be always the best solution. You can just use it as an off-node layer with the mam.node.js wrapper. [Here is an example](https://github.com/demichele/mam)